# Protractor open new browser for each test

Tags: protractor

I want to open new browser for each new test starting at  'describe(info[i].TestName'. Both Login and Start App are part of one test.

Right now both tests run in same browser and then browser is closed.

```
for (let i in info) {

            describe(info[i].TestName, () => {

            beforeAll(function () {
            browser.get('http://abcsite.com');
            });

            describe('Login', () => {
                Login.start();
            });

            describe('LibraryApp', () => {
                LibraryApp.app(info[i]);
            });

});
}
```

Comment: Would `browser.restart()` solve your issue? https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.restart

Comment: @BenMohorc thank you for answering. I tried browser.restart. But then it restarts after Login then again restarts after LibaryApp. I want it to restart /launch new browser only before Login and close the browser after Library App, open new browser before Login and close the browser after LibaryApp and so on (for loop).

Comment: I would expect you to be able to put browser.restart() before your browser.get() it would only run once per iteration. Another solution would be to run a `afterAll()` with a browser.close or something

Comment: @BenMohorc I tried browser.restart() before browser.get() as suggested. But then it keeps restarting the browser even before reaching login (never reached login)

Comment: @BenMohorc thanks for your suggestion. It worked after this:

Comment: for (let i in info) {

        describe('Start', () => {

            beforeAll(function () {
                browser.restart(); });             describe(info[i].TestName, () => {

            beforeAll(function () {
            browser.get('http://abcsite.com');
            });

            describe('Login', () => {
                Login.start();
            });

            describe('LibraryApp', () => {
                LibraryApp.app(info[i]);
            });

});
}