# Protractor launch new browser for each test

Tags: protractor

Not sure if this is the right thing to do. But really could use some help. Been stuck at this problem below for a few days.

[Protractor open new browser for each test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839220/protractor-open-new-browser-for-each-test)

Comment: verify your `conf.js` file

Answer (score 1):

Try [restartBrowserBetweenTests](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L546) in protractor conf.js

```
  /**
   * If true, protractor will restart the browser between each test. Default
   * value is false.
   *
   * CAUTION: This will cause your tests to slow down drastically.
   */
  restartBrowserBetweenTests?: boolean;
```